# What are some practical applications of mathematical/formal logic to science and humanities?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, applications, first-order-logic, nonclassical-logic

I am studying a bit of this and so far it seems that, apart from math and computer science, the discipline of Logic is very self facing, with logicians proving things for other logicians. It left me wondering about interdiscipliary work. Specifically, can classical(propositional and first order predicate) and/or non-classical (i.e., fuzzy, intuitionist, relevant etc) logics provide unique insights or analysis in the following domains:

1. History,
2. Law,
3. Psychology,
4. Engineering?

I know this is a bit broad, just looking for  smattering of concrete examples indexed to these domains.

Thanks

Comment: Most of the uses I am aware of are actually abuses that make me cringe and die a little bit whenever I see them.

Comment: Fuzzy Logic does have a few things to say about Linguistics, according to K. H. Lee's *First Course in Fuzzy Theory and Applications*, which I suppose is pertinent to both Psychology and History (in some sense); other applications will surely be found *ibid*.

Comment: "Applications of Modal Logic in Linguistics" http://www.indiana.edu/~iulg/moss/linguistics.pdf

Comment: @mt_ : Thanks for that. Although it is still very theoretical in its applicaiton in linguistics, at least it is related to human activities. I can't help but think that the use of logic here is more of a diagramming tool than as a way to get insight. This is different than, say, math as applied to physics, where math provides actual insights not already apparent to the practitioner.

Comment: Modern logic has applications to other areas, but mostly to other areas of mathematics.  For example, descriptive set theory (especially invariant descriptive set theory and the study of Borel equivalence relations) has many applications.

Comment: This calls to mind a [remark of Vaughan Pratt](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/1998-February/001248.html): "It has been my impression from having dealt with a lot of lawyers over the last twenty years that the logic of the legal profession is rarely Boolean, with a few isolated exceptions such as jury verdicts which permit only guilty or not guilty, no middle verdict allowed.  Often legal logic is not even intuitionistic, with conjunction failing commutativity and sometimes even idempotence.  But that aside, excluded middle and double negation are the exception rather than the rule."

Comment: Mathematical logic is used *everywhere* in philosophy of language and mind, with direct applications to psychology. See for instance the twentieth-century debates on functionalism in philosophy of mind or the semantic of proper names in philosophy of language. We saw early applications of formal logic to philosophy of mind and metaphysics in Kant and the American pragmatists - just look at Peirce's analysis of the forms of thought. And later, of course, Frege, Russell, and Wittgenstein famously deployed (abused) mathematical logic in their analyses of language and metaphysics.

Comment: From what I've read fuzzy logic does have some things to say about psychology and artificial intelligence.  Fuzzy logic also does have applications in engineering.  The Sendai subway comes as an example.  Bart Kosko lists a bunch of engineering and other types of applications of fuzzy logic in his book Fuzzy Thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that Mathematical Logic is not the "foundation" of Mathematics; refer to **Y.Manin**, *A Course in Mathematical Logic for Mathematicians* (2nd ed, Springer - 2010; pag.xi) :

> Foundational problems are for the most part passed over in silence. Most likely, logic is capable of justifying mathematics to no greater extent than biology is capable of justifying life.

Math Logic is Mathematics : Proof Theory, Model Theory, Computability Theory. But ML is a "strange" branch of Math because it has as his object of study Math itself.

The impressive success of Math is with application (through physics, engineering, economy) to the understanding of the external world.

ML has its application in the study of a particular "human activity" : the mathematician's one and its "products" : mathematical theories.